# how to create a credit memo in magento programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create a Magento Credit Memo programmatically but Magento shows me a credit memo with zero totals.

```
$incrementID = "100000016";
$orderMagento = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementID);

$convertOrder = new Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Order ();
$creditmemo = $convertOrder->toCreditmemo ( $orderMagento );

$items = $orderMagento->getAllItems();  

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $_eachCreditMemoItem = $convertOrder->itemToCreditmemoItem ( $item );
    $_eachCreditMemoItem->setQty ($item->getQtyInvoiced());
    $_eachCreditMemoItem->register ();
    $creditmemo->addItem ( $_eachCreditMemoItem );
    $totalQty += $item->getQtyInvoiced ();
} 

$creditmemo->refund();
$creditmemo->setTotalQty ( $totalQty );
$creditmemo->collectTotals();

$orderCreditMemoStatusCode = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED;
$orderCreditMemoStatusComment = $comment;
$saveTransaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')->addObject ($creditmemo )->addObject ( $orderMagento )->save ();
$orderMagento->addStatusToHistory ( $orderCreditMemoStatusCode, $orderCreditMemoStatusComment, false );
$orderMagento->save ();
```

I have find this code in StackOverflow and I am trying to use it but it doesn't work as well.

Why the totals are not updated? Which is the right way to create it?

[image: Magento Credit Note Page]
thanks

Comment: The best approach is to follow the steps and code that handles this in the credit memo controller. Put log lines inside the controller, to see how the data should look and then try to format your input similar to the one required by the controller. Actually this is what you should do when trying to replicate in code something that is done in a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make credit memo from paid invoices. So first you need to get all paid invoices from your order:

```
$invoices = array();
foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
    if ($invoice->canRefund()) {
        $invoices[] = $invoice;
    }
}
```

Then go throughout the invoices and make credit memo:

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    $creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice);
    $creditmemo->refund();
}
```

Hope it works for you.